# Preserve the orderInCategory of items having showAsAction="ifRoom" set

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

How can I preserve the order defined by `android:orderInCategory` while the first options menu shows as one action when it's the only item of the menu?

I have defined two options menus, which get inserted by two different Fragments. If both Fragments are not displayed simultaneously, everything looks like intended.

The first options menu shows one action:
[image: Menu of Fragment1]

The second options menu shows one action and one menu item:
[image: Menu of Fragment2]

Now if I have both Fragments displayed within one Activity at the same time, I was hoping, the items would obey the value of `android:orderInCategory` and show as one action and two menu items:

> [image: How it should look like]

Instead there are two actions shown and only one menu item:
[image: How it looks like]

So how would I achieve the intened result?

---

The `Fragment1` inserts:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action3"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:orderInCategory="500"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Action3"/>
</menu>
```

The `Fragment2` inserts:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action1"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Action1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action2"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Action2"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android respects the order but android:showAsAction takes precedence. Because you specified action2 as "never", and the other 2 as "ifRoom", it displays the other 2 first as actions items, then action2 in the overflow menu.

To get the behavior you want you should set showAsAction to "never" for action3.